# how to make edit field accept number up to two decimal value in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to accept a number in edit Field up to two decimal value(for example 123.34).I am using 
new EditField(EditField.FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC);
and
new EditField(EditField.FILTER_INTEGER);

How can i do this

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend [NumericTextFilter](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/text/NumericTextFilter.html) class and override `validate()` method to conform your rules. And set the customized filter instance to your field via `setFilter()` method.

Comment: Can we match string to a patten in blackberry.If yes then how. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can do it with regular expressions. There is a J2ME regular expressions implementation: http://code.google.com/p/regexp-me/

Comment: jakarta-regexp-1.2 I downloaded and copied the src code into my application but it some classes showing error

Comment: Not sure that jakarta-regexp package is compatible with mobile devices. Try "regexp-me" package.